# Windows 10 Apps, right-clicking on Taskbar icons, Start Menu/Search Bar and clicking Windows System Tray icons all fail

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, context-menu, notification-area

So in the middle of the day (worked fine in the morning), I come to find out that all the crap listed in my Title starts to happen. Internet Explorer 11 also doesn't fully function: some sites fail to load or are incomplete. I am at my wit's end as I've already tried a number of "fixes" to no avail. Non-windows System tray icons function correctly (eg. Steam, Outlook 2013, nVidia, etc.)

- Powershell command to reset Windows 10 Apps
- ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES permissions up the wazoo to various folder/registries
- System restore to 1 week ago and 3 weeks ago (oldest I have)
- SFC and DISM commandline commands
- I even made an empty profile and that didn't work either.

Everything works fine in SAFE mode, but that doesn't help me at all. I'm pretty sure I'm screwed because if a System Restore doesn't fix it, what short of a reset/reinstall of Windows 10 will?

Please tell me someone has something as I really don't want to do that. One "different" thing I have is that my Users folder is located away from my OS (C:) drive due to space restrictions of the SSD. Nothing has gone wrong in the 1 year I've had Windows 10 up until now.

Edit: Firefox became broke from Restores and I find out I can't even download files in IE 11. My PC is seriously borked. Had to get a USB from another PC.

Edit 2: This is the following error from Event Viewer whenever I try to Right-click something on the taskbar, if it helps. Geez, it looks like it's just another Windows 10 app that fails, argh.

```
Faulting application name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.10586.218, time stamp: 0x56ff3cf7
Faulting module name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.10586.218, time stamp: 0x56ff3cf7
Exception code: 0xc000027b

Fault offset: 0x0000000000085831

Faulting process id: 0x2494

Faulting application start time: 0x01d1a8bbd9657856

Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps
\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe

Report Id: 89b411e9-b943-43da-85a5-3f094e99ad8a

Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy

Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39526/discussion-on-question-by-j-r-dabinett-windows-10-apps-right-clicking-on-taskba).

Comment: I posted in the chat. Microsoft wants to know some more details. I asked a contact for help.

Comment: also run this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3152599

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I found it here
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html

Open `cmd` prompt as admin, then

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

It's normal for them to hang at 20% for a long time so just wait.

Comment: I already performed the 3rd command before. Executing all three of them didn't fix it. The first 2 also said there was no corruption.

Comment: it seems like I have also experienced this issue in the past. I guess I just reboot the system and it works again for a while but it doesn't happen on a daily basis.